# Matlab: list of trees

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct

I have implemented a binary tree in Matlab using 'struct' type elements as nodes. An N-node tree has, say, N such structs.

My problem is that I have M such trees, each having a different number of nodes, N_1, N_2, ..., N_M. How can I hold these trees in a list or array which can be iterated? Several trials like struct of structs did not seem to work.

Edit: I want to do something like the following. myClassTree returns a tree with N_i nodes.

```
trees = struct;
for i=1:nTrees
    tree = myClassTree(train(bags(i,:),:), entropy, depth);
    trees(i) = tree;
end
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code?  A struct of structs should work.  We can also talk about cell arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is to create a cell array.  Simply replace `trees(i) = tree;` with `trees{i} = tree;` (note braces, rather than parenthesis).

Cell arrays are useful whenever you want to store an array of mixed data types.  To access elements of a cell array, you can use the braces again.  For example, this should work as you expect:

```
currentTree = trees{someIndex};
```

---

The code that you posted creates an array of structs, which only works if the structures have the same fieldnames.

If you wanted (not recommended) you could created a struct of structs, but doing somehting like this `trees.(['n' sprintf('%04d',i)]) = tree;`.  (But please don't.)

Comment: Thanks indeed. Trees should be initialized like this:    trees = {};

Comment: Also, you'll improve performance if you replace `for i=1:nTrees` with `for i=nTrees:-1:1`, reversing the order of the loop.  This naturally preallocates the array.